# Why isn't IE11 remembering DOM changes on history(-1)?

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, firefox, dom

I am working on a submission form for my website, which contains a table with several regular rows of form input.

When a user "deletes" a row using a delete button, I simply clear all the inputs, and call the jQuery "appendTo" function to move the row to the end of the table.

Here is where I'm running into an issue:

- in Firefox, I can click the submit button and use the Back button or a history(-1) call - the reordering is remembered.
- in IE, when I do the same thing, the elements I "deleted" are restored to their original position in the DOM, their original values restored. If I entered anything in the row at the end of the table, it is lost.

I would restore the inputs from session, but one of them is a file input - these can't be modified except by the user.

Is there another way to get around this? Or can anyone share insight as to why it is happening?

EDIT:

The workflow requirement is that I continue to the next page, which displays confirmation for user contact info. The user is directed to return to the previous page to change the information if it is incorrect. Otherwise, they continue, and the final submission is processed.

Comment: Use Ajax and stay on the page

Comment: The workflow requirement is that I continue to the next page, which displays confirmation for user contact info. The user is directed to return to the previous page to change the information if it is incorrect. Otherwise, they continue, and the final submission is processed.

Comment: Probably has something to do with HTTP being stateless.

Comment: What's strange is that the inputs on the form are originally pre-populated with values from JSP. If I don't change the DOM (by deleting, etc), the values aren't restored. It's almost as if IE is requesting the JSP again, but only if the DOM was changed.